# Kubernetes: how to access service if nodePort is random?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I'm new to K8s and am currently using Minikube to play around with the platform. How do I configure a public (i.e. outside the cluster) port for the service? I followed the [nginx example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-the-service), and K8s service tutorials. In my case, I created the service like so:

```
kubectl expose deployment/mysrv --type=NodePort --port=1234
```

The service's port is 1234 for anyone trying to access it from INSIDE the cluster. The minikube tutorials say I need to access the service directly through it's random nodePort, which works for manual testing purposes:

```
kubectl describe service mysrv | grep NodePort
...
NodePort:                 <unset>  32387/TCP
# curl "http://`minikube ip`:32387/"
```

But I don't understand how, in a real cluster, the service could have a fixed world-accessible port. The nginx examples describe something about using the LoadBalancer service kind, but they don't even specify ports there...

Any ideas how to fix the external port for the entire service?

Comment: If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by `--service-node-port-range flag (default: 30000-32767)`.If you want a specific port number everytime, you can specify a value in the `nodePort field` at service creation time on your service manifest file.

Comment: Setting the nodePort as explained in the docs is not a good solution because it only controls the port at the node level. When accessing the service from outside the entire cluster without minikube (on GKE for example), how is the nodePort even relevant? It has to be something at the load balancer level but I don't know where. BTW Ingress is not an option since my traffic is not http-based (it's TCP though)

Comment: Hi, if its non-http traffic, then i would suggest you to use exteranlIP in  k8s service object. then you can access non-http application with  externalIP:svcPort. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Comment: Suresh Vishnoi, thanks, it works! The problem was that I had to run 'minikube tunnel' in a separate shell, to get an external IP (otherwise it stays 'pending' forever). The 'port' config is indeed accessible outside the cluster as you mentioned

Answer (score 18):

> The minikube tutorials say I need to access the service directly through it's random nodePort, which works for manual testing purposes:

When you create service object of type `NodePort` with a `$ kubectl expose` command you cannot choose your `NodePort` port. To choose a `NodePort` port you will need to create a `YAML` definition of it.

**You can manually specify the port in service object of type `Nodeport`  with below example:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello # selector for deployment
  ports:
  - name: example-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1234 # CLUSTERIP PORT
    targetPort: 50001 # POD PORT WHICH APPLICATION IS RUNNING ON 
    nodePort: 32222 # HERE!
```

You can apply above `YAML` definition by invoking command:
`$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml`

Above service object will be created only if `nodePort` port  is available to use.

> But I don't understand how, in a real cluster, the service could **not** have a fixed world-accessible port.

In clusters managed by cloud providers (for example GKE) you can use a service object of type `LoadBalancer` which will have a fixed external IP and fixed port.

Clusters that have nodes with public IP's can use service object of type `NodePort` to direct traffic into the cluster.

In `minikube` environment you can use a service object of type `LoadBalancer` but it will have some caveats described in last paragraph.

## **A little bit of explanation:**

### [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

`Nodeport` is exposing the service on each node IP at a static port. It allows external traffic to enter with the `NodePort` port. This port will be automatically assigned from range of `30000` to `32767`.

You can change the default `NodePort` port range by following [this manual](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2019/02/20/kubernetes-service-node-port-range).

You can check what is exactly happening when creating a service object of type `NodePort`  by looking on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345488/12257134).

Imagine that:

- Your nodes have IP's:

  - `192.168.0.100`
  - `192.168.0.101`
  - `192.168.0.102`
- Your pods respond on port `50001` with `hello` and they have IP's:

  - `10.244.1.10`
  - `10.244.1.11`
  - `10.244.1.12`
- Your Services are:

  - `NodePort` (port `32222`) with:

    - `ClusterIP`:

      - IP: `10.96.0.100`
      - `port`:`7654`
      - `targetPort`:`50001`

A word about `targetPort`. It's a definition for port on the **pod** that is for example a web server.

**According to above example you will get `hello` response with:**

- `NodeIP:NodePort` (all the pods could respond with `hello`):

  - `192.168.0.100:32222`
  - `192.168.0.101:32222`
  - `192.168.0.102:32222`
- `ClusterIP:port` (all the pods could respond with `hello`):

  - `10.0.96.100:7654`
- `PodIP:targetPort` (only the pod that request is sent to can respond with `hello`)

  - `10.244.1.10:50001`
  - `10.244.1.11:50001`
  - `10.244.1.12:50001`

You can check access with `curl` command as below:

`$ curl http://NODE_IP:NODEPORT`

---

**In the example you mentioned:**

```sh
$ kubectl expose deployment/mysrv --type=NodePort --port=1234
```

What will happen:

- It will assign a random port from range of `30000` to `32767` on your `minikube` instance directing traffic entering this port to pods.
- Additionally it will create a `ClusterIP` with port of `1234`

In the example above there was no parameter `targetPort`. If `targetPort` is not provided it will be the same as `port` in the command.

Traffic entering a `NodePort` will be routed directly to pods and will not go to the `ClusterIP`.

From the `minikube` perspective a `NodePort` will be a port on your `minikube` instance. It's IP address will be dependent on the hypervisor used. Exposing it outside your local machine will be heavily dependent on operating system.

---

### [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

There is a difference between a service object of type `LoadBalancer`(1) and an external `LoadBalancer`(2):

- Service object of type `LoadBalancer`(1) allows to expose a service externally using a cloud provider’s `LoadBalancer`(2). It's a service within Kubernetes environment that through service controller can schedule a creation of external `LoadBalancer`(2).
- External `LoadBalancer`(2) is a load balancer provided by cloud provider. It will operate at Layer 4.

Example definition of service of type `LoadBalancer`(1):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - port: 1234 # LOADBALANCER PORT 
      targetPort: 50001  # POD PORT WHICH APPLICATION IS RUNNING ON 
      nodePort: 32222 # PORT ON THE NODE
```

Applying above `YAML` will create a service of type `LoadBalancer`(1)

Take a specific look at:

```yaml
  ports:
    - port: 1234 # LOADBALANCER PORT
```

This definition will simultaneously:

- specify external `LoadBalancer`(2) `port` as 1234
- specify `ClusterIP` `port` as 1234

Imagine that:

- Your external `LoadBalancer`(2) have:

  - `ExternalIP`: `34.88.255.5`
  - `port`:`7654`
- Your nodes have IP's:

  - `192.168.0.100`
  - `192.168.0.101`
  - `192.168.0.102`
- Your pods respond on port `50001` with `hello` and they have IP's:

  - `10.244.1.10`
  - `10.244.1.11`
  - `10.244.1.12`
- Your Services are:

  - `NodePort` (port `32222`) with:

    - `ClusterIP`:

      - IP: `10.96.0.100`
      - `port`:`7654`
      - `targetPort`:`50001`

**According to above example you will get `hello` response with:**

- `ExternalIP`:`port` (all the pods could respond with `hello`):

  - `34.88.255.5:7654`
- `NodeIP:NodePort` (all the pods could respond with `hello`):

  - `192.168.0.100:32222`
  - `192.168.0.101:32222`
  - `192.168.0.102:32222`
- `ClusterIP:port` (all the pods could respond with `hello`):

  - `10.0.96.100:7654`
- `PodIP:targetPort` (only the pod that request is sent to can respond with `hello`)

  - `10.244.1.10:50001`
  - `10.244.1.11:50001`
  - `10.244.1.12:50001`

`ExternalIP` can be checked with command: `$ kubectl get services`

Flow of the traffic:
Client -> `LoadBalancer:port`(2) -> `NodeIP:NodePort` -> `Pod:targetPort`

### [Minikube: LoadBalancer](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer/)

> **Note:** This feature is only available for cloud providers or environments which support external load balancers.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Create external LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)*
>
> On cloud providers that support load balancers, an external IP address would be provisioned to access the Service. On Minikube, the `LoadBalancer` type makes the Service accessible through the `minikube service` command.
>
> --  *[Kubernetes.io: Hello minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/)*

`Minikube` can create service object of type `LoadBalancer`(1) but it will not create an external `LoadBalancer`(2).

The `ExternalIP` in command `$ kubectl get services` will have pending status.

To address that there is no external `LoadBalancer`(2) you can invoke `$ minikube tunnel` which will create a route from host to `minikube` environment to access the `CIDR` of `ClusterIP` directly.

Comment: In an on-prem environment it's easy to understand the use case of a fixed `NodePort`. And in a cloud environment it's easy to understand the use case of a `LoadBalancer`. But what's the use case of a randomly assigned `NodePort`? Who is that useful for and how is it meant to be used?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in Dawid Kruk’s answer,

> Traffic entering a NodePort will be routed directly to pods and will
> not go to the ClusterIP.

But as k8s documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the
> NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, **to which the NodePort Service
> routes**, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the
> NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting
> :.

**Traffic entering a NodePort did go to ClusterIP.**