# How to Configure Kubernetes in Hairpin Mode

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to enable hairpin connections on my Kubernetes service, on GKE.

I've tried to follow the instructions here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/ to configure my kubelet config to enable hairpin mode, but it looks like my configs are never saved, even though the edit command returns without error.

Here is what I try to set when I edit node:

```
spec:
  podCIDR: 10.4.1.0/24
  providerID: gce://staging/us-east4-b/gke-cluster-staging-highmem-f36fb529-cfnv
  configSource:
    configMap:
      name: my-node-config-4kbd7d944d
      namespace: kube-system
      kubeletConfigKey: kubelet
```

Here is my node config when I describe it

```
Name:         my-node-config-4kbd7d944d
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
kubelet_config:
----
{
  "kind": "KubeletConfiguration",
  "apiVersion": "kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "hairpinMode": "hairpin-veth"
}
```

I've tried both using "edit node" and "patch". Same result in that nothing is saved. Patch returns "no changes made."

Here is the patch command from the tutorial:

```
kubectl patch node ${NODE_NAME} -p "{\"spec\":{\"configSource\":{\"configMap\":{\"name\":\"${CONFIG_MAP_NAME}\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\",\"kubeletConfigKey\":\"kubelet\"}}}}"
```

I also can't find any resource on where the "hairpinMode" attribute is supposed to be set.

Any help is appreciated!

------------------- edit ----------------

here is why I think hairpinning isn't working.

```
root@668cb9686f-dzcx8:/app# nslookup tasks-staging.[my-domain].com
Server:     10.0.32.10
Address:    10.0.32.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   tasks-staging.[my-domain].com
Address: 34.102.170.43

root@668cb9686f-dzcx8:/app# curl https://[my-domain].com/python/healthz
hello
root@668cb9686f-dzcx8:/app# nslookup my-service.default
Server:     10.0.32.10
Address:    10.0.32.10#53

Name:   my-service.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.38.76

root@668cb9686f-dzcx8:/app# curl https://my-service.default.svc.cluster.local/python/healthz
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-service.default.svc.cluster.local port 443: Connection timed out
```

also if I issue a request to localhost from my service (not curl), it gets a "connection refused." Issuing requests to the external domain, which should get routed to the same pod, is fine though.

I only have one service, one node, one pod, and two listening ports at the moment.

--------------------- including deployment yaml -----------------
Deployment

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 50001
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTPS
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-service
    servicePort: 60000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 60000
      - path: /python/*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 60001
```

service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port
    port: 60000
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: python-port
    port: 60001
    targetPort: 50001
  type: NodePort
```

I'm trying to set up a multi-port application where the main program trigger a script to run through issuing a request on the local machine on a different port. (I need to run something in python but the main app is in golang.)

It's a simple script and I'd like to avoid exposing the python endpoints with the external domain, so I don't have to worry about authentication, etc.

-------------- requests sent from my-service in golang -------------

```
https://[my-domain]/health: success
https://[my-domain]/python/healthz: success
http://my-service.default:60000/healthz: dial tcp: lookup my-service.default on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host 
http://my-service.default/python/healthz: dial tcp: lookup my-service.default on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host 
http://my-service.default:60001/python/healthz: dial tcp: lookup my-service.default on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host 
http://localhost:50001/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50001: connect: connection refused 
http://localhost:50001/python/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:50001: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Hello. `Hairpinning` should work without any additional configuration. How did you test to came to conclusion that it doesn't work?

Comment: So from the pod, I can nslookup "[service name].default" which resolves to the same IP address that my external address resolves to. I can query my external address, but when I query [service name] it times out. I added the nslookup+curl outputs.

Comment: I see in your testing methodology that you are trying locally to `curl https://my-service`. What I think the issue is that you are trying to connect to the pod through a service(`clusterIP`) specifying the wrong port. Could you show the `YAML` of this service that is exposing this pod?

Comment: oh no! that's entirely possible since i'm totally new to kubernetes. I'm including my yaml file as well

Comment: thank you so much for your help @DawidKruk

Comment: I see now. I will write an answer with some explanation. Is it possible to: `issuing a request on the local machine on a different port` do as a localhost connection?

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure what you mean? but i'll include the requests I sent and their results too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Kubelet reconfiguration in `GKE`

---

**You should not reconfigure `kubelet` in cloud managed Kubernetes clusters like `GKE`. It's not supported and it can lead to errors and failures.**

### `Hairpinning` in `GKE`

---

`Hairpinning` is enabled by default in `GKE` provided clusters. You can check if it's enabled by invoking below command on one of the `GKE` nodes:

```sh
ifconfig cbr0 |grep PROMISC
```

The output should look like that:

`UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1460 Metric:1`

Where the **`PROMISC`** will indicate that the hairpinning is enabled.

Please refer to official documentation about debugging services: [Kubernetes.io: Debug service: a pod fails to reach itself via the service ip](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#a-pod-fails-to-reach-itself-via-then-service-ip)

### Workload

---

Basing only on service definition you provided, you should have an access to your python application on port `50001` with a pod hosting it with:

- `localhost`:`50001`
- `ClusterIP`:`60001`
- `my-service`:`60001`
- `NodeIP`:`nodeport-port` (check `$ kubectl get svc my-service` for this port)

I tried to run your `Ingress` resource and it failed to create. Please check how `Ingress` definition should look like.

Please take a look on official documentation where whole deployment process is explained with examples:

- [Kubernetes.io: Connect applications service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)
- [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes engine: Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)
- [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes engine: Load balance ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress)

Additionally please check other  StackOverflow answers like:

- [Stackoverflow.com: Kubernetes how to access service if nodeport is random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116792/12257134) - it describes how you can access application in your pod
- [Stackoverflow.com: What is the purpose of kubectl proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332972/what-is-the-purpose-of-kubectl-proxy/54345488#54345488) - it describes what happen when you create your service object.

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.

Comment: hmm, i think ingress should be working because accessing through my external domain works (with url matching). localhost:50001 fails for "connection refused" and "my-service:60001" fails with no such host. I added these result to my post

Comment: Please invoke command: `kubectl get pods,services,ep` and update your question with it. To clarify. You have one pod with 2 applications running on ports: `8080` and `50001`? If yes, please **exec into it** and try to run `curl localhost:8080` and `curl localhost:50001`. Let me know the results. After that please do the same from another pod but with `curl my-service:6000` and `curl my-service:6001`. Could you tell what's the reason behind you curling the `/python/healthz`?

Comment: Yea. When I curl directly from inside the pod, `localhost` and `my-service` both work as expected. I'm just using the `/python/healthz` path because that's the handler i implemented.

Comment: As I said please invoke command: `kubectl get pods,services,ep` and update your question with it. Your service is lacking `selector`. How exactly did you expose your application to the Internet?

Comment: i found the problem and you're right, it has nothing to do with hairpin mode. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.