# configuration nodeport but kubernetes still give port range

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I declared a service in **nodePort** mode. but there's something I don't understand. maybe I'm getting confused.
The **nodePort**, forwarded to the service’s **port**, and received on the **targetPort** by the pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: frontend
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
        product: {{ .Values.product }}
        environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
        version: {{ .Values.version }}
        component: frontend
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      ports:
      - port: 6001
        targetPort: 6001
        protocol: TCP
      selector:
        app: countly-frontend
```

when I list the services on kubernetes I see this :

```
service/countly-frontend        NodePort       10.xx.xx.12    <none>        6001:31145/TCP    110s
```

normally I should see **6001:6001** and not **6001:31145** ?
The app is listening on port 6001 as you may have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might work:

```
ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6001
      targetPort: 6001
```

Or if you could try changing `targetPort` to `nodePort` in your original

Answer (score 0):

It's how kubernetes service nodeport works.
NodePort service bind on random port in the range 30000-32767. 
If you want to specify the bind port add **nodePort** attribute to set it ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) ) but it must be in the required range.
For the example I choose 30007 :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    product: {{ .Values.product }}
    environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
    version: {{ .Values.version }}
    component: frontend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 6001
    targetPort: 6001
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30007
  selector:
    app: countly-frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify some misconceptions:

---

**You cannot change the `nodePort` port range for a managed Kubernetes cluster like `GKE`**.

---

A word about `nodePort` from official Kubernetes documentation:

> [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport): Exposes the Service on each  Node’s IP at a static port (the `NodePort`). A `ClusterIP` Service, to which the `NodePort` Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the `NodePort` Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
>
> --  [Kubernetes.io: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

`nodePort` port ranges from `30000` to `32767`.

What you see here:

> when I list the services on kubernetes I see this :
>
> ```sh
> service/countly-frontend        NodePort       10.xx.xx.12    ><none>        6001:31145/TCP    110s
> ```

Specifically:  `6001:31145/TCP` is **correct**.

### Example:

Assume that there is a pod with an application running on port `50001`.

This is a `service.yaml` of above application:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
    - name: hello-port
      port: 5678 # CLUSTER-IP PORT
      targetPort: 50001 # PORT WHICH YOUR APPLICATION IS RUNNING ON
      nodePort: 30051 # NODEPORT PORT 
  type: NodePort
```

Output of `$ kubectl get services`:

```yaml
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP                                           PORT(S)           AGE
hello-service      NodePort       10.86.1.195   <none>                                                5678:30051/TCP   25h
```

You will have an access to your application by:

- `NodeIP:NodePort(30051)` (external access)
- `ClusterIP:port(5678)` (internal access)
- `PodIP:targetPort(50001)`  (internal access)

If you would like to expose your application on port `6001` for external use you can try a service type of `LoadBalancer`.

There are answers on StackOverflow that are going deeper in this topic:

- You can check what is exactly happening when creating a service object of type `NodePort` by looking on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345488/12257134).
- [Services explanation from minikube perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116792/12257134)

Please take a look on official documentation about exposing applications on a `GKE` cluster: 
[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes engine: Exposing apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.